# Возник вопрос как реализовать функцию наблюдатели(просмотры)?

Tags: ios, swift, изображения, uibutton

Добрый вечер! ребята затруднился внедрении функции такой как просмотры, как правильно в языке программирования это функция называется.Я просмотрел несколько уроков и хотел проконсультироваться.Это функция делается через протокол и делегат?Когда человек заходить просматривает страницу и зачисляется просмотр.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Это должно быть реализовано на стороне сервера, я бы предположил что должна быть 
удаленная БД ([Realm](https://realm.io/products/realm-database/) например, или [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/)), в самом приложении реализовать довольно просто (одна проблема - не на плодить много запросов с обновлением счетчика).
А протоколы и делегаты это уже детали реализации, самый банальный вариант в viewDidApear  записи посылать запрос на увеличение счетчика, или обновлять только на устройстве  и синхронизировать периодически с сервером

Comment: У меня Parse.А можете пример скинуть?